# Localizing XIB files - why there is a need

Tags: ios, localization, xib

I am beginner in iOS.
I learned how to localize XIB files.
This way two versions of my XIB file are created, say one for
English version and one for Spanish.

Here is sample of the spanish localized XIB:
[image]

I was curious why there is need for localizing XIB files?
I know how to localize any string using string tables
and `NSLocalizedString()` method. Is localizing XIB files
good because it is not possible/easy to use localized strings as titles
for the controls in the interface builder?

Answer (score 1):

If you move to storyboards and autolayout you don't need to localize your UI, you just need to provide the localised strings files.

Answer (score 0):

> Is localizing XIB files good because it is not possible/easy to use
>   localized strings as titles for the controls in the interface builder?

The backside is, when you need to show a message to the user sometimes needed the label localized text without colon. The xib provides name with colon and without. Sometimes hard to keep in evidence what / where is in localized xib.

You can make an utility software to make easier the localisation of strings and editing those inline with many languages. That why I prefer strings localized over xib.